# React useRef() with setInterval() in useCallBack() function not clearing upon clearInterval()

Tags: reactjs

I have this stopwatch code, which shows the elapsed time on screen. (React Component)

It all works okay, but calling "clearInterval(increment.current)" (which using using a useRef() for scope in React) doesn't seem to really "stop" the Interval. It keeps logging "Triggered" in the console (every second) - and I don't follow why it's still being called after clearInterval() when currentActivityOn === false. (And if the timer is triggered several times, it triggers more than once per second.)

Any suggestions?

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useCallback, useContext } from 'react'
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'

import useLocalStorage from '../../hooks/useLocalStorage'
import { FlowTimeContext } from '../../services/flow/flow-time.context'
import { useStyles } from './grid-stopwatch.styles'

export default function GridStopwatch() {
  const classes = useStyles()

  const { currentActivityOn } = useContext(FlowTimeContext)

  const [timerStartTime, setTimerStartTime] = useLocalStorage('timerStartTime', '')
  const [timer, setTimer] = useLocalStorage('timer', 0)
  const increment = useRef(null)

  const handleTimerRun = useCallback(() => {
    increment.current = setInterval(() => {
      if(timerStartTime !== ''){
        const new_timer = ((Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)) - timerStartTime)
        setTimer(new_timer)
      } else {
        console.log("Triggered") // Why is this being called continually?
      }
    }, 1000)
  }, [setTimer, timerStartTime])

  const handleReset = useCallback(() => {
    clearInterval(increment.current)
    setTimer(0)
    setTimerStartTime('')
  }, [setTimer, setTimerStartTime])

  const handleStart = useCallback(() => {
    if(timerStartTime === ''){
      var start = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)
      setTimerStartTime(start)
    }
  }, [timerStartTime, setTimerStartTime])

  const formatTime = () => {
    const getSeconds = `0${timer % 60}`.slice(-2)
    const minutes = `${Math.floor(timer / 60)}`
    const getMinutes = `0${minutes % 60}`.slice(-2)
    const getHours = `0${Math.floor(timer / 3600)}`.slice(-2)

    return `${getHours}h : ${getMinutes}m : ${getSeconds}s`
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(currentActivityOn === true){
      handleStart()
      handleTimerRun()
    } else {
      handleReset()
    }
  }, [currentActivityOn, handleStart, handleReset, handleTimerRun])

  return (
    <Container maxWidth='xl' className={classes.container}>
      {currentActivityOn && (
        <Typography variant='subtitle2' gutterBottom>
          Current Activity Duration: {formatTime()}
        </Typography>
      )}
    </Container>
  )
}
```

Comment: you should probably add `increment`  as a dependency of the `handleTimeRun` `useCallback`.

Comment: I've added increment as a dependency, but that didn't make any difference. (I guess since it's a useRef, the code linting didn't complain about not having it; but it doesn't complain about it either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the useEffect gets triggered twice in this case. So handleTimerRun got called twice, and it seems each time there was an additional interval started that was never cleared.

```
  const handleTimerRun = useCallback(() => {
    if(timerStartTime !== ''){
      increment.current = setInterval(() => {
        const new_timer = ((Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000)) - timerStartTime)
        setTimer(new_timer)
      }, 1000)
    }
  }, [setTimer, timerStartTime, increment])
```

For now I'm able to work around this by moving the condition before starting the interval, so it only gets started once. This seems to solve my issue, but is a workaround rather than truly understanding "how" there can be an additional interval started that is assigned the same id. (and seemingly can't be "stopped")

Further clarity on that would certainly be appreciated.

It seems that if I console log increment.current, it keeps increasing - whereas I thought it would be a consistent ID...? (mutable yes, but consistent when not being mutated.)